# A veces se crean 2 elementos en vez de 3 en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios, set, elementos

Al crear conjuntos y querer agregarles 3 elementos, solo se agregan 2, **NO EN TODOS LOS CASOS**, dejo aquí el código para que podáis ayudarme.

```
from random import randint
U={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
A=set()
B=set()
C=set()
contador=0

while contador<3:
    contador+=1
    A.add(randint(0,9))
    B.add(randint(0,9))
    C.add(randint(0,9))

print(f"{A} \n{B} \n{C}")
```

Comment: A, B y C son `set`: no almacenan elementos repetidos y `randint` puede repetir valores ... al azar.

Answer (score 1):

Es difícil verlo si apenas conoces python, pero **set()** no admite valores iguales(entre otras características, [ver más](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)), te dejo un ejemplo del por qué no te devuelve lo que esperas. **La solución es que uses [listas](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_list.asp) y utilices su método append**

```py
set1 = set()
set1.add(1)
set1.add(1)
set1.add(3)

print(set1)

# //→ {1,3}
```